# Rename project in Roslyn

Tags: roslyn

How can I change name of (`IProject`) in Roslyn?
I found only the extension method `UpdateAssemblyName()`, but it do something else (of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roslyn doesn't currently offer a way to rename a project, sorry.

Comment: It's ok. I understand it's only CTP now. I hope it is on feature-list in "must-have" column :). The only way I see for now is recreation of whole project. Is there any better way?

Comment: Your best approach might just be to not use Roslyn and some other API. Renaming the project itself is easy -- just rename the file. But if you have a solution file, you'd have to update that too, and I don't know of any library for that.

Comment: I'm working with in-memory solution created directly by Roslyn. There are no project files in my app. But it's not crucial, I'm only playing with Roslyn.